# How can I code to count the number of react warnings in a console

Tags: reactjs, git, husky

Our team is pushing code with a lot of warnings. We want to set up a git pre-hook with husky asking a question whether you want to merge the code to master.

I want to write code to ask a yes or no question before git commit to tell about the number of warnings before a commit.

Answer (score 1):

I would create wrapper for `console.warn` and `console.error`. The wrapper should report each call somewhere. Also it should check, if NODE_ENV is testing, otherwise leave console methods untouched. Then build and run your app with `NODE_ENV === testing`, gather data and report to user. Imho it would be too heavy for precommit hooks.